# Why isn't there ActionLink in MvcContrib.FluentHtml?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mvccontrib

While perusing through the various helpers for MvcContrib's [FluentHtml](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=FluentHtml&referringTitle=Documentation) project (and loving the composability of it all), I realized that there was no option for creating anchor tags that go to actions, like that of `Html.ActionLink(...)`.

I can't understand why something like this wouldn't have already been implemented. I'd love to do something like this:

```
<div>
    @(this.ActionLink("Go Here!", "AwesomeAction", "Awesome")
    .Class("amazing")
    .Attr("awesome", true))
</div>
```

I understand this is more of a discussion, which I also understand is frowned upon as SE. In light of that, could someone help me understand how something like this might be created in the FluentHtml project? If it does indeed work, I would love to spruce it up and submit it as a patch.

Thanks! Feedback is welcome!

Comment: I think the built in `Html.ActionLink` flexible enough so there is no need to wrap/replace it. Your sample looks like this `@Html.ActionLink("Go Here!", "AwesomeAction", "Awesome", null, new { @class = "amazing", awesome = true})`

Comment: Well, yes, there's no *new* functionality in FluentHtml, but that's not the problem the project is trying to solve. It's that "[Methods with long signatures are hard to read, and it takes investigation to see what’s happening...HtmlHelper is not easily extensible](http://lunaverse.wordpress.com/2008/11/24/mvcfluenthtml-fluent-html-interface-for-ms-mvc/)". After using it a bit, I'd have to say I agree.